# PDO Inserts multiple rows in single query

Tags: php, sql, arrays, pdo, insert

im trying to put multiple php arrays into a insert statement and put it in a sql database. I dont have much expierence in programming, so i tried this. But you cant bindValue a php array so it gives null. How can i fix this.

$voornamen,$geslachten,$achternamen,$geboortedata are four seperate php arrays what contains data of multiple user names, date births, surnames etc.

php code to insert:

```
$query = $conn->prepare( "INSERT INTO ReserveerCursusCursisten 
    (Geslacht, Achternaam, Voorletters, Geboortedatum) VALUES (:geslachten, :achternamen, :voornamen, :geboortedata, 0, 0)");
for($i = 0; $i < count($achternamen); $i++)
{
    $stmt->bindValue(':geslachten', $geslachten);
    $stmt->bindValue(':achternamen', $achternamen);
    $stmt->bindValue(':voornamen', $voornamen);
    $stmt->bindValue(':geboortedata', $geboortedata);
    $stmt->execute();
}

if ($stmt->execute())
{
  echo "query is gelukt";
}
else
{
    echo "query is niet gelukt";
}
```

Comment: You must build a query in the format "Insert into t (a,b,c) values (a1,b1,c1),(a2,b2,c2),.....(aN,bN,cN), basically using a foreach.

Comment: inside your for loop you need to access the specific entry in your arrays. ... `bindValue(':geslachten', $geslachten[$i]);` ...$achternamen[$i] ... etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way to build the query: First you build the whole SQL, then you bind the values to each column and row:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO ReserveerCursusCursisten 
(Geslacht, Achternaam, Voorletters, Geboortedatum) VALUES ";

$subqueries = [];

for($ii=0; $ii< count($geslachten);$ii++) {
    $subqueries []="(:ges$ii,:ach$ii,:voo$ii,:geb$ii)";
}

$query .= implode(",", $subqueries);

$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);

for($ii=0; $ii< count($geslachten);$ii++) {
    $stmt->bindValue(":ges$ii", $geslachten[$ii]);
    $stmt->bindValue(":ach$ii", $achternamen[$ii]);
    $stmt->bindValue(":voo$ii", $voornamen[$ii]);
    $stmt->bindValue(":geb$ii", $geboortedata[$ii]);
}
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: i get this error running your code Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$subqueries' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: now i get this error when running your edited code: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Comment: Thanks for you help! It's working only now im trying a php array dataformat d/m/y into the database. Now im trying to format it to Y/m/d but it doesnt work on a array.   Do you know how to do this? i get this error: Call to a member function format() on array php

Comment: Guess you'll have to convert that data array in a single string. And upvote my answer :-)

Comment: I think you missed the upvoting, dude

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following:

- your arrays must have equal count of elements
- variable `$query` is never used, change it to `$stmt`
- you have four column names, but six values in SQL statement
- pass array item to `binValue()`, not the array

Example:

```
<?php
$stmt = $conn->prepare(
    "INSERT INTO ReserveerCursusCursisten 
        (Geslacht, Achternaam, Voorletters, Geboortedatum) 
    VALUES 
        (:geslachten, :achternamen, :voornamen, :geboortedata)
");
for($i = 0; $i < count($achternamen); $i++)
{
    $stmt->bindValue(':geslachten', $geslachten[$i]);
    $stmt->bindValue(':achternamen', $achternamen[$i]);
    $stmt->bindValue(':voornamen', $voornamen[$i]);
    $stmt->bindValue(':geboortedata', $geboortedata[$i]);
    if ($stmt->execute() === false) {
        echo "query is niet gelukt";
    } else {
        echo "query is gelukt";
    }
}
?>
```

Notes:

You may skip `bindValue()` and pass parameters to `execute()`. In this case all parameters are treated as strings (`PDO::PARAM_STR`), while with using `bindValue()` you may define parameter data type (one of `PDO::PARAM_*` constants).

```
<?php
$stmt = $conn->prepare(
    "INSERT INTO ReserveerCursusCursisten 
        (Geslacht, Achternaam, Voorletters, Geboortedatum) 
    VALUES 
        (:geslachten, :achternamen, :voornamen, :geboortedata)
");
for ($i = 0; $i < count($achternamen); $i++)
{
    $params = array($geslachten[$i], $achternamen[$i], $voornamen[$i], $geboortedata[$i]);
    if ($stmt->execute($params) === false) {
        echo "query is niet gelukt";
    } else {
        echo "query is gelukt";
    }
}
?>
```

Part of PHP documentation about prepared statements:

> Calling PDO::prepare() and PDOStatement::execute() for statements that
>   will be issued multiple times with different parameter values
>   optimizes the performance of your application by allowing the driver
>   to negotiate client and/or server side caching of the query plan and
>   meta information. Also, calling PDO::prepare() and
>   PDOStatement::execute() helps to prevent SQL injection attacks by
>   eliminating the need to manually quote and escape the parameters.

Comment: This is not very gelukt :-)

Comment: I think he wants to do it in a single SQL call.

Comment: @Amarnasan I'm not sure, because OP uses `for` loop. And yes,  this answer shows multiple inserts and this is one of the reasos for using prepared statements. Thanks for this comment.

Comment: @Amarnasan i get this error running your code Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bindValue() on null

Comment: @zhorov He literally said in the title "Inserts multiple rows in SINGLE query"

Comment: @Amarnasan Ah, I missed that part :). But I still think that one `preprare()` call and multiple `execute()` should be the first option. Thanks.

Comment: @zhorov It is WAY more efficient to send one single queries than a lot of them. And also more coherent.